# How to use IPython with Python3.3 in Fedora 18

Tags: python, fedora, ipython

I've got both Python 3.3 and Python 2.7 installed on my PC. After installing IPython 0.13.1 on Fedora 18 using the Software installer it defaults to Python 2.7.

I've little experience in both Linux  and Python (had a couple of attempts to learn it). I've had a look at [IPython configuraton documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/overview.html) but I'm still stuck. Any help/pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug filled in bugzilla https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=784947 and for now is impossible to run ipython with python3 in Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Which Python to use is not something you configure in IPython. IPython is just a package, so you must install it separately for each Python in which you want it to be importable.  If your distro does not have a package for IPython on Python 3, you can always easy/pip install it:

```
pip-3.3 install ipython
```

(Note: you may need to install pip first, you may need to prefix with `sudo`, or do `--user`, etc.)